# Power Automate PDF Hyperlink in Email

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow that is triggered when an item or a file from a Sharepoint List is modified. The Title of the Sharepoint stores PDFs that differ from each entry. I want to send emails that have hyperlinks to the PDF of the modified items. How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-insert-a-quot-Clck-Here-quot-in-an-email/td-p/10753

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Send-Email-V2-Preview-does-not-add-hyperlinks-to-email-alerts/idi-p/182074